# Schedule a Background Job from a Cloud Code Function in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I have a couple of different background jobs that need to be run in order to reset a player. I would like to be able to schedule all of these jobs, once each, from a cloud code function.

Put differently: can you schedule a one-time job using parse cloud code from a parse function?